# QGIS 3.10.5 GPS live tracking

Tags: gps, tracking

I use QGIS 3.10.5 and GARMIN GPSMAP 64S connected with USB cable to do live tracking. The GPS Information panel shows that I am connected but nothing happens on the screen.

Comment: have you setup up your port connection, there is few details to go on here.